# can't ping from mac os to xp

Tags: macos, networking, ping

my mac can ping others' computer which is xp,but they can't ping mine,I have closed the firewall,is there any other configs?thank you in advance.
I have searched in google,but can't find the helpful method.

Comment: Is it a wired or wireless connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that the Mac OS firewall is disabled, you should check the settings of the router. As a starting point you could connect the two computers directly through crossover cable and check if the issue persists. If it doesn't it most certainly is related to the router device.

Comment: I am able to ping to gateway but not to that box

Comment: Ankits-MacBook-Pro:~ Compumatrice$ ping 192.168.100.9
PING 192.168.100.9 (192.168.100.9): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- 192.168.100.9 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
Ankits-MacBook-Pro:~ Compumatrice$ ping 192.168.100.254
PING 192.168.100.254 (192.168.100.254): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.100.254: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.272 ms

^C
--- 192.168.100.254 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss

Comment: I have disabled firewall on both box

Answer (score 0):

The problem sounds like a firewall issue (probably on your mac) versus a connectivity issue since ping works in one direction. Perhaps ingress ping (icmpv4) traffic is blocked on your mac? Go to System Preferences > Firewall > Turn Off and try this again?